# Sending File Over Bluetooth

Tags: objective-c, ios, file, bluetooth, sharing

I'm developing an application that has feature which involves sending data over bluetooth. I've tested sending data with GameKit framework and it works fine. My question is "Is that correct way to go?" or should I use some other way of transporting data over bluetooth?

An additional question: when I'm sending data, both devices (one sending and one receiving) have to init GKPeerPickerController and show it. Is there a way for receiver to get notification for connection without calling GKPeerPickerController, so that sender can send a file and receiver can just confirm he wants to receive file (without looking for sender aka showing GKPeerPickerController)?

Tnx, 
Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GKSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class and its [delegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSessionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/GKSessionDelegate) to handle peer to peer connection programmatically and implement your own views.